# Not being able to get json data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I am trying to make dynamic dropdown list in a Laravel project.
So I am trying to do it using Jquery and Ajax.
I am using the following script to do my work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#country').on('change', function(){
        var country_id = $('#country').val();
        var op=" ";
        alert(country_id);
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'{{route('getBranch')}}',
            data:{'id':country_id},
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert(data[0].branch_name);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, my 'on change' is working, I can see that through the alert. It is getting the country ID. This country ID is saved in my 'branch' table as country_id. I am trying to get data from 'branch' table using the country_id.
When I am using alert() to see data it says 'undefined'.
My route is:

```
Route::get('/get_branch',[
'as' => 'getBranch',
'uses' => 'EmployeeInfoController@countryBranch',
'title' => 'Getting Branch Name'
]);
```

This route should hit the following function in the controller:

```
public function countryBranch(Request $request){
    $country_id = $request->id;
    $branch = Branch::where('country_id',$country_id)->get();
    return response()->json($branch);
}
```

This is my first time using Jquery and Ajax. So don't know anything else. I am following other peoples code to achieve this. But it seems it's not working for me.
I am using Laravel 5.5 with XAMPP.

Comment: First of all it looks like you have one "}" to many after the success function.

Comment: what is your console.log(data); shows

Comment: Try with `url:"{{route('getBranch')}}"` - you are using single quotes twice so JavaScript stops parsing string after second quote mark instead after fourth. Plus this @KungWaz said.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `get()` returns collection but `json()` method takes an array so use `toArray()` after getting results.

you can try like this

```
public function countryBranch(Request $request){
    $country_id = $request->id;
    $branch = Branch::where('country_id',$country_id)->get()->toArray();
    return response()->json($branch);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I have figured out the problem this morning. Actually I was working on an Office management project. So the routes we create had to be permitted to be used. I forgot that and was stuck in this. When I permitted the routes for the user everything started working. Now it's completely functional.